# Compare contents of three arrays/json using loops php

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have a system with many lines of JSON documents and I want to compare each 1st line and two others and if elements of the last exists in the first,extract or print the content of the field remaining in the first.I 'm obliged to use loops.My problem is that when I print I get many times the result.

Ex:

```
echo json_encode($A=array("haha"=>"BINGO","deux"=>"deux","trois"=>"trois")).'</br>';
echo json_encode($B=array("haha"=>"BINGO")).'</br>';
echo json_encode($C=array("trois"=>"trois")).'</br>';

//{"haha":"BINGO","deux":"deux","trois":"trois"} Line 1
//{"haha":"BINGO"} Line 2
//{"trois":"trois"} Line 3


for($i=0; $i<sizeof($A); $i++){
    for($j=0; $j<sizeof($B) ;$j++){
        for($k=0; $k<sizeof($C); $k++){
            if($A[haha]==$B[haha] AND $A[trois] == $C[trois]){
                print_r ($A[deux]);echo'</br>';

                /*Print
                deux
                deux
                deux */
                //I would like to print just one time 'deux'

                }
        }
    }
}
```

Any suggestions please,Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 0):

I was a bit unsure about what you wanted, but this will provide a single "deux":

```
$A=array("haha"=>"BINGO","deux"=>"deux","trois"=>"trois");
$B=array("haha"=>"BINGO");
$C=array("trois"=>"trois");

$one_and_two = array_diff($A, $B);
$one_and_three = array_diff($A, $C);

$diffs = array_intersect($one_and_two, $one_and_three);

var_dump($diffs);
```

Comment: Thanks but I have to use loops I have many JSON/array documents and I have to loop into them...